# localization not working with strong-globalize in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, globalization, strongloop, loopback

I am using strong-globalize for doing localization for my loopback project.

I have done the setup and messages are correctly fetched for the English language which is default.

But problem is when I am trying to access messages for other languages it still returns the English message.

Here is my code:

**Server.js**

```
var SG = require('strong-globalize');
SG.SetRootDir(__dirname);
SG.setDefaultLanguage('en');
g = SG();
```

**Coupon.js (Model with remote methods)**

```
 var SG = require('strong-globalize');
 var g = SG();
 var Negotiator = require('negotiator');
```

**Coupon.js inside remote method**

```
var negotiator = new Negotiator(request);
var acceptedLanguage = negotiator.language();
g.setLanguage(languageSelected);
var message = g.m('valid coupon');
```

I used command `slt-globalize -d` to generate messages for English (`en`).
Then i created a new folder for `es` where I have pasted the `messages.json` file which is available in the `en` folder.
Then manually updated all the messages in that file with Spanish text but still i am getting English messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, see if this works first:

```
g.setLanguage('es');
```

then,

```
var availableLanguages = ['es', 'en'];
var languageSelected = negotiator.languages(availableLanguages);
g.setLanguage(languageSelected);
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: How to generate messages.json for other languages?  What i am doing is i am running slt-globalize -e which generates messages.json for en. Then i am copying that messages.json to es folder. There replacing english messages with es.

Comment: Is the loopback app accessible somewhere like github.com?Regarding messages.json for other languages, there are two ways: just like you did for Spanish, and using **slt-globalize -t** (-t stands for `translation`)  Details in README on npmjs.com.